# Would it be possible to economically repair 9V-SWB?

Tags: wing, aircraft-maintenance, boeing-777

[image: Passenger photo after the fire was out (Photo: Steve Herman):]

Damage suffered by the right wing of 9V-SWB, a Boeing B777-300.

The complete incident details could be found [here](http://avherald.com/h?article=49a58209&opt=0).

My question is, would it be possible to repair this aircraft economically, so that it could be reused in future and the repairing costs get recovered from future options?

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information, especially at this early stage, to be able to determine the extent of the damage.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the damage [has been categorized](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=20160627-0) as "substantial", meaning that it will be costly, but the aircraft has not been written off.

I would expect that the wing will be completely replaced (thus it will not be cheap), but given the current status anything more is speculation (and what I wrote already is).

---

**Update:** the aircraft was [returned to service](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/777/9V-SWB-Singapore-Airlines/2KN2CKl7) on 12 Nov 2016.